# Getting this error when trying to run a java gui in linux: java.io.InvalidClassException: javax.swing.text.JTextComponent; local class incompatible?

Tags: java

I'm trying to run a java gui app in a linux terminal with the command: java -jar javaGUI.jar. This is a gui pulled from a github, and I'm not sure about going in and editing any of the code. I've seen posts about serializing, but I'm simply trying to open the GUI through my linux terminal.

If its helpful, this is what I get for the java version:

openjdk version "1.8.0_152-release"

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1056-b12)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.152-b12, mixed mode)

This is the full error:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: javax.swing.text.JTextComponent; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -8043358055867187832, local class serialVersionUID = -7141373156355680543
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:616)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1829)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1713)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1829)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1713)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1986)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1919)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1529)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.access$700(ObjectInputStream.java:213)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$GetFieldImpl.readFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2395)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFields(ObjectInputStream.java:592)
        at java.awt.Container.readObject(Container.java:3719)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2122)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
        at java.beans.Beans.instantiate(Beans.java:190)
        at java.beans.Beans.instantiate(Beans.java:77)
        at WindowsWithFirst.TheWay.initComponents(TheWay.java:65)
        at WindowsWithFirst.TheWay.<init>(TheWay.java:45)
        at WindowsWithFirst.FirstW.<init>(FirstW.java:41)
        at com.main.Main_gui$1.run(Main_gui.java:62)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Container must be non-null
        at javax.swing.GroupLayout.<init>(GroupLayout.java:374)
        at WindowsWithFirst.TheWay.initComponents(TheWay.java:285)
        at WindowsWithFirst.TheWay.<init>(TheWay.java:45)
        at WindowsWithFirst.FirstW.<init>(FirstW.java:41)
        at com.main.Main_gui$1.run(Main_gui.java:62)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Use the same Java version

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/what-is-a-serialversionuid-and-why-should-i-use-it#285809